# I want to print the number of times an element is repeated in an array of random numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, memory

Hi wanted to display repeated elements of a Random array whose size can be specified by the user. The problem I am getting in the output is , the function is printing a repeated number as many times as it has been repeated but I want to print it only once.
Here is my code and output following the former:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int array_size = 0;
int *my_array;
int i = 0;

printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
scanf("%d",&array_size);

my_array = malloc(array_size * sizeof my_array[0]);
if(NULL == my_array) {
    fprintf(stderr,"MEMORY ALLOLCATION FAILED \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for(i=0;i<array_size;i++){
    my_array[i] = rand()%array_size;
}
printf("What's in the array:\n");
for(i = 0;i<array_size;i++){
    printf("%d ",my_array[i]);
}
printf("\n");

display_repeats(my_array, array_size);
free(my_array);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void display_repeats(int *a,int n){
int *repeats;
repeats = malloc(n * sizeof repeats[0]);
int i=0;
int j=0;
int count = 0;


for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(j=0;j<n;j++){

     if(a[i] == a[j]){
        count++;
    }
   }
if(count>1){
repeats[i] = count;
printf("%d occurs %d times\n",a[i],repeats[i]);
}


 count = 0;

 }

free(repeats);
}
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
Enter the size of the array:
5
What's in the array:
3 1 2 0 3 
3 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 2 times
```

I want "3 occurs 2 times" to print once.
Please help!

Comment: Your loop catch the second time '3' is reached - try save all element that you find already and ignore them if repeated

Comment: @DavidWinder could you please elaborate :) ? Maybe show me some code !

Comment: The approach is the problem - you're counting the occurrences as many times as they happen to be in the array (if occurring more than once). You can sort the array first, then the nested loop approach will work, provided you add an i++ every time you find a match.

Comment: Please use some code for the answer! I am a newbie to C so that might help me

Comment: Did you cover any type of sorting in your class? If you did then it's probably best that you implement that bit yourself and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Best solution will be to check for each a[i] if he is the first of its kind (assuming sorting is out of question). Add for loop before the j one that will check for any occurrence in the array previous to i - if you find any continue to i+1. Also start the inner j loop with initialisation of j=i. This will keep O(n) and solve also more then 2 reoccurrence

Comment: @DavidWinder could u please write the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your code realizes 3 is repeated twice, in this block:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){

  for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    if(a[i] == a[j]){
    count++;
    }
  }

  if(count>1){
    repeats[i] = count;
    printf("%d occurs %d times\n",a[i],repeats[i]);
  }
}
```

When `i` is equal to 0, it will look at the array and realize that 3 is repeated, so `count>1` will be `true`. Then, when `i` is equal to 4, `count>1` will be `true` again, and you get the double print.

In order to fix this, I would create an array that stores the numbers that have already been verified as repeated and check against that.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your case, value of elements < size_array, so can take this approach.

```
memset(repeats, 0, n*sizeof(repeats[0]));
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(j=0;j<n;j++){
     count = repeats[a[i]];
     if(count>0)
        break;
     if(a[i] == a[j]){
        count++;
     }
  }
  repeats[a[i]] = count;
```

The idea is to store the count for each value and check before starting search for each new value to check if it has already been counted.

Comment: Indeed, just checked on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
```

So, don't compare the same one element with itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `display_repeats()`, you may simply update 2 lines and add 3 lines to make your program have the correct behaviour. And we will see it later: **we can optimize the final code using C99 syntax and the comma C operator, to write far less lines than your original code (9 lines instead of 20 lines!)**.

So, in this answer, you will find how to get the final code that has the correct behaviour and is very short, shorter than your initial code:

```
void display_repeats(int *a, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] == -1) continue;
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      if (a[i] == a[j]) count++, a[j] = -1;
    if (count > 1) printf("%d occurs %d times\n", a[i], count);
  }
}
```

**The idea is to set to -1 each array value that has matched a previous one, just after the count increment. Because you do not want to count this value again.**

So simply do the following:

- In the two lines where you write `count = 0`, replace 0 by 1, because you are sure that each number in the list must be counted at least one time.

  This way, you can avoid checking the case where i equals j in the inner loop: it is already taken into account in count. So add `if (i == j) continue;` at the beginning of the inner loop.
- With the previous updates, you are now sure that when you increment count, in the inner loop, j is not equal to i. Therefore, you can change the value of `a[j]` without changing `a[i]`, in the array.
- So, add `a[j] = -1;` just after having increased count. This way, when i will be incremented to check for a new count of a new value, it is impossible that the new counted value has already been counted.
- Finally, you do not want to count how many times -1 is in the array. But you have replaced some values with -1. So simply add  `if (a[i] == -1) continue;` at the beginning of the outer loop to avoid counting how -1 there are in the array.

This intermediate code is:

```
void display_repeats(int *a,int n) {
int *repeats;
repeats = malloc(n * sizeof repeats[0]);
int i=0;
int j=0;
int count = 1;

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if (a[i] == -1) continue;
  for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
    if (i == j) continue;
    if(a[i] == a[j]) {
      count++;
      a[j] = -1;
    }
  }
  if(count > 1) {
    repeats[i] = count;
    printf("%d occurs %d times\n",a[i],repeats[i]);
  }
  count = 1;
 }
free(repeats);
}
```

**Now, we can optimize this code.**

First, we can avoid testing `a[i] == a[j]` when j <= i: if such a case happens, we know that we have previously displayed the count for a[j] (the number of times a[j] appears in the array). Therefore we can replace `for (j=0; j < n; j++) {` by `for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {`.

With this last update, we know that the first line of the inner loop will never match: i can not be equal to j. So we can remove this line (`if (i == j) continue;`).

Note that the values stored in the repeats array are only used to get the value of count in the printf() call. So we can remove every reference to the repeats array and simply use count in the printf() call.

Now, you can see that we set count to 1, two times. We can do it only one time, if we do not set it to 1 at the end of the main loop, to prepare a new loop, but at the beginning.

Now, note that i, j and count have the same type, so only one line may be used to define them: `int i = 0, j = 0, count = 1;`. More over, i and j are defined later in the for loops, so no need to define their initial value here. So we can simply write `int i, j, count = 1;`. But count is now defined at the beginning of the outer loop, so we do not need to define it previously. So we only need to define i, j and count without an initial value: `int i, j, count;`.

The new intermediate code is:

```
void display_repeats(int *a, int n) {
  int i, j, count;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] == -1) continue;
    count = 1;
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i] == a[j]) {
        count++;
        a[j] = -1;
      }
    }
    if (count > 1) printf("%d occurs %d times\n", a[i], count);
  }
}
```

**Using C99 syntax**

But we can do more, using the C99 specification: we can define a variable with the for instruction: we can write `for (int i = ...)`. No more need to define it previously. So we can avoid having to write `int i, j, count;`, we will define them at first use:

```
void display_repeats(int *a, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] == -1) continue;
    int count = 1;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i] == a[j]) {
        count++;
        a[j] = -1;
      }
    }
    if (count > 1) printf("%d occurs %d times\n", a[i], count);
  }
}
```

**Using the comma C operator**

Again, we can do much better! We can use the comma operator (`,`): it is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand, discards the result, evaluates the second operand and returns its value. Using the comma operator, we can transform `count++; a[j] = -1;` to a single instruction: `a[j] = (count++, -1)`. But we can avoid the parenthesis writing `count++, a[i] = -1`. Now, we do not need a block for the if statement, since there is only one instruction. Therefore, we can remove a lot of parenthesis.

The final code is:

```
void display_repeats(int *a, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] == -1) continue;
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      if (a[i] == a[j]) count++, a[j] = -1;
    if (count > 1) printf("%d occurs %d times\n", a[i], count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I got it working with the above ideas!
here is what I got..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
 int array_size = 0;
 int *my_array;
 int i = 0;

 printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
 scanf("%d",&array_size);

 my_array = malloc(array_size * sizeof my_array[0]);
 if(NULL == my_array) {
    fprintf(stderr,"MEMORY ALLOLCATION FAILED \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for(i=0;i<array_size;i++){
    my_array[i] = rand()%array_size;
      }
   printf("What's in the array:\n");
   for(i = 0;i<array_size;i++){
    printf("%d ",my_array[i]);
    }
   printf("\n");

  display_repeats(my_array, array_size);
  free(my_array);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }

 void display_repeats(int *a,int n){
   int *freq;


   freq = malloc(n * sizeof freq[0]);
   int i=0;
   int j=0;
   int count = 0;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   freq[i] = -1;
    }

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   count = 1;
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
      if(a[i]==a[j]){
        count++;
        freq[j] = 0;
       }
     }
 if(freq[i]!=0){
    freq[i] = count;
  }
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  if(freq[i]!=1 && freq[i]!=0){
    printf("%d occurs %d times\n",a[i],freq[i]);
  }
 }
free(freq);
}
```

Comment: I am not near a computer right now - You can simplify this solution and avoid allocate the freq array - but if that work for you great!